# Python: add a new mimetype

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, mime-types, mime

How can I add a new mimetype using the add_type() function in the mimetypes package?  Do I need to do something with the python file system?  If I try something like: add_type('text/new', 'new') nothing seems to happen.

Comment: What did you expect to happen with `add_type()`? Did you use `guess_extension()` afterwards, for example?

Comment: Yes, I did: `add_type('text/new', 'new')` `init()` `guess_type('hello.new')`   I would have expected it to return ('text/new', None) but instead it returned (None, None) as if it didn't recognize the type I added.

Comment: Don't call `init()`, that just resets things again!

Comment: Oh, thank you.  Still no luck though, I'm getting (None, None) without the init() as well.

Comment: Figured it out.  I needed to put a period before the second argument in add_type.

Comment: Perhaps that's worthy of a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you feel up to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87023/discussion-between-michael-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extension needs to have a period in front of it.  `add_type('text/new', '.new')` works.